# Embed Python/C++ code in React Native?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-native

I am planning on working on a personal project where I utilize React native for most of the Business Logic and Front End.

I want it to work on Windows 10, but it would be great if it was compatible with IOS/Android as well.

While I know React native itself has that capability, the catch here is that I want to utilize heavy machine learning throughout the project in Python for now, and then perhaps C++.

I did some research and many people suggested running a flask server and calling the Python code via its API. The problem with that is that that then delegates the machine learning tasks to the server, and not the client.

1) Is there a way to "embed" the python server to only exist in the React-Native back-end (Node js) environment? Or perhaps in this case it just calls a python script and awaits results?

2) Is is possible to achieve this task while also packaging it in a '.exe' or '.apk' file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in re-using some Python code, take a look at http://www.transcrypt.org, which promises cross-compilation of Python to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly answer your question but I'm sure it does help you take a decision.

So, with my experience I can suggest you these things:

1) **Use React-Native bridge**: If you're relying on ML algorithms that are readily available and you don't need much of modifications at deeper level, then you can consume the APIs provided in [Windows AI and ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/). I'm suggesting you this because you are saying that you'll be developing it for Windows. If you want the same for Android and iOS, I guess there are APIs readily available which are similar to Windows'. You can find about react native bridge and how can you consume the above mentioned APIs in these links - [Link1](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) and [Link2](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)

2) **Use NAPI or C++ Addon for Node.js**: As you said you can be relying on C++ in future, I would suggest this to you. This allows you to consume C++ Libraries in Node.js. Also, as Python is C-callable, if I'm not wrong we can call Python in C++ and vice-versa. I suggest you to read about these things before you proceed. You can read about [NAPI](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) and [C++ Addons for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

You can also find a lot of blog posts and tutorials on the things I mentioned both the alternative I've given above.